# Could not transfer metadata net.minidev:json-smart/maven-metadata.xml from/to clojars

Tags: maven

I'm trying to build an Apache Storm topology, and getting the following error while running `mvn assembly:assembly`.

```
$ mvn assembly:assembly
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building WordCount 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:assembly (default-cli) @ WordCount >>>
Downloading: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/twitter/carbonite/1.5.0/carbonite-1.5.0.pom
Downloading: https://clojars.org/repo/com/twitter/carbonite/1.5.0/carbonite-1.5.0.pom
Downloading: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://clojars.org/repo/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repository.apache.org/snapshots/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 1.9 KB/sec)
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata net.minidev:json-smart/maven-metadata.xml from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/): hostname in certificate didn't match: <repo.clojars.org> != <v.ssl-384-default.ssl.fastly.net> OR <v.ssl-384-default.ssl.fastly.net>
Downloading: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/minidev/json-smart/1.3.3/json-smart-1.3.3.pom
Downloaded: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/minidev/json-smart/1.3.3/json-smart-1.3.3.pom (2 KB at 6.7 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.094s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jan 19 13:13:40 KST 2022
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/1924M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project WordCount: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.c3.example:WordCount:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [junit:junit:jar:4.11 (test), org.apache.storm:storm-core:jar:2.2.0 (provided)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.twitter:carbonite:jar:1.5.0: Could not transfer artifact com.twitter:carbonite:pom:1.5.0 from/to clojars (https://clojars.org/repo/): hostname in certificate didn't match: <repo.clojars.org> != <v.ssl-384-default.ssl.fastly.net> OR <v.ssl-384-default.ssl.fastly.net> -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

My pom.xml is:

```xml
$ cat pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.c3.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>WordCount</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>WordCount</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>clojars</id>
            <url>https://clojars.org/repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <storm.version>2.2.0</storm.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
            <version>${storm.version}</version>
            <!-- keep storm out of the jar-with-dependencies -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
                    <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
                    <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
                    <mainClass>${storm.topology}</mainClass>
                    <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.c3.example.WordCountTopology</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>log4j2.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I tried before, this project seemed to be built without any error.

I don't get why it fails to collect junit and storm-core dependencies.

I'm not used to maven project, so any links or comments would be appreciated.

Comment: This seemed to be the issue `hostname in certificate didn't match: <repo.clojars.org> != <v.ssl-384-default.ssl.fastly.net> OR <v.ssl-384-default.ssl.fastly.net>` which Java version do you use?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm using 1.8.0_112

Comment: Simply too old...upgrade your JDK to most recent of JDK 8...